# What do you call a set with multiple partial orders?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $Q$ be a set that is partially ordered by $\leq_A$ and $\leq_B$.
Conventionally, $(Q, <_A)$ and $(Q, <_B)$ are called "posets", but what would $(Q, \leq_A, \leq_B)$ be called?

Comment: Why do you start with $Q$ a topological space, not just a set? Do you want both partial orders to induce the same topology?

Comment: Changed to set.

Comment: Diversified.  :-)